# NPM , cannot access plugin before initialization?

Tags: npm, gulp

npm v7.13.0

I'm trying to follow the examples for using the [gulp-git plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-git). I have in my `gulpfile.js` file

```
const { dest, parallel, series, src } = require('gulp');
const git = require('gulp-git');

function doSomething() {
  if(getBranch().includes("release/")) {
    // foo
  }
  else {
    // bar
  }
}

function getBranch() {
  git.revParse({args:'--abbrev-ref HEAD'}, function (err, branch) {
    return branch;
  });
}
```

...and do...

```
$ npm install gulp && npm install gulp-git --save-dev
$ npm run some-command
```

...and get the following error.

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'git' before initialization
    at getBranch (/some_path/gulpfile.js:44:3)
    at parseGitTag (/some_path/gulpfile.js:28:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/some_path/gulpfile.js:18:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
    at requireOrImport (/some_path/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/shared/require-or-import.js:19:11)
```

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have git installed? I've seen this before but it was because I hadn't run `npm install` after cloning the project.

Comment: Yes I have git installed.

Comment: The stack trace seems pretty clear: `getBranch` is being called by `parseGitTag` in the gulpfile, before `const git` is declared.